# How do I perform a join using multiple columns as different string criteria?

Tags: r, join, sqldf

I would like to perform a complex join, one that considers multiple columns as different kinds of criteria.

I want to assign each fruit a category, based on whether or not it contains a string, the strings it may contain, and strings it does NOT contain.

I have a vector of fruits:

```
head(fruit) 
[1] "apple"       "apricot"     "avocado"     "banana"      "bell pepper" "bilberry"
```

And the criteria to assign each fruit is detailed here:

```
 fruitAssignment <- data.frame(assignment = c('Apple','Berry','Black','Melon','Melon','Melon','Currant'),
       contains = c('apple','berry','black','honeydew','melon','cantaloupe','currant'),
       mayContain = c(NA,'black',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
       doesNotContain = c(NA,NA,'berry',NA,NA,NA,NA))

  assignment   contains mayContain doesNotContain
1      Apple      apple       <NA>           <NA>
2      Berry      berry      black           <NA>
3      Black      black       <NA>          berry
4      Melon   honeydew       <NA>           <NA>
5      Melon      melon       <NA>           <NA>
6      Melon cantaloupe       <NA>           <NA>
7    Currant    currant       <NA>           <NA>
```

Exceptions:

- If there are no assignments that meet the criteria, I would like to assign the fruit simply as 'Fruit'.
- If there are multiple assignments that meet the criteria, I would like to assign it as 'Fruit' as well.
- The criteria shouldn't be case sensitive.

So this sample of the join would look like this:

```
 dplyr::sample_n(fruit, size=5)
         fruit assignment
1   redcurrant    Currant
2 blackcurrant      Fruit
3    pineapple      Apple
4   blackberry      Berry
5      coconut      Fruit
```

Whatever packages are used to do this is fine.

Comment: "fruit","apple" do not appear in your `fruitAssignment`, and your column `assignment` have values starting with uppercase letters. Please specify properly the output you want

Comment: edited to include proper sample output. I only need the criteria to assign `fruit` to an `assignment` to not be case sensitive. Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a join is appropriate here, it's more of a classification task. Using regular expressions to look for matches between your search term and your classification table:

```
fruit <- c("redcurrant", "blackcurrant", "pineapple", "blackberry", "coconut")

fruitAssignment <- data.frame(assignment = c('Apple','Berry','Black','Melon','Melon','Melon','Currant'),
                              contains = c('apple','berry','black','honeydew','melon','cantaloupe','currant'),
                              mayContain = c(NA,'black',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                              doesNotContain = c(NA,NA,'berry',NA,NA,NA,NA),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

fun <- function(fruit, fruitAssignment) {

  fruitAssignment[,2:4] <- apply(fruitAssignment[,2:4],
                                 2,
                                 function(x, fruit) sapply(x, grepl, fruit, ignore.case = TRUE),
                                 fruit = fruit)
  fruitAssignment[is.na(fruitAssignment)] <- FALSE

  x <- fruitAssignment %>%
    filter(!doesNotContain, contains | mayContain)

  if (nrow(x) == 1)
    return(x$assignment)
  "Fruit"

}

sapply(fruit, fun, fruitAssignment) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  setNames(c("fruit", "assignment"))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  fruit        assignment
  <chr>        <chr>     
1 redcurrant   Currant   
2 blackcurrant Fruit     
3 pineapple    Apple     
4 blackberry   Berry     
5 coconut      Fruit
```